# ADC differential filter for DC signals

Tags: adc, filter

I am trying to build an ADC module using the ADS1110 ADC and the TLS2272 op amp. This is more a problem of composition than a filter design problem.

The 16bit ADS1110 runs at the amazing speed of 15 SPS with a range of 0-4.096V. Unfortunately it is not a fully differential ADC and to reach 16bit on the whole range you need to use a Vref of 2.048V on the AIN- pin (see datasheet for more info). To restore the differential feature I am planning of using an opamp in differential mode, with a lp filter (fc=20Hz).

This is the circuit I came up with, but it's wrong, because the op amp is single supply and it can't detect if the signal ground noise ripple goes below 0V. Also note that the cutoff freq of this circuit is 200Hz not 20, ignore it.

[image]

I thought about some variations but I don't know which is the better one:

1) Remove the SK, use the freed opamp unit to buffer Vref, sum vref to both inputs of the differential filter

2) Remove the SK, use the freed opamp unit to sum the signal ground to Vref, feed this to the (-) input of the ADC

3) Something else

Please, give advice.

**EDIT**:

**Main goal is to filter noise from both the signal and its ground, make the difference and feed it to the AIN+ of the ADC. Also, "signal" maybe is too much, I just need to read a fixed DC voltage.**

Explanation of the Vref trick:

The ADC reads the (+) input within +/- 2V the (-) input. Since my signal ground is probably close to the ADC ground and the ADC can't read negative voltages I need to move the (-) input to 2V to use the full range with full precision.

More info: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa133a/sbaa133a.pdf

Comment: your LP cutoff is far  too high. It needs to be lower than 15 Hz / 2 = 7.5 Hz.

Comment: So, what are the voltages you *want* to detect? You only mention that you need to get some negative ripple into the picture, but I'm not really seeing you well-define the specs of your overall system. Actual bandwidth (lower and upper frequencies) of the signal you want to observe would be very interesting, too!

Comment: Also, the ADS1110 **has** a differential input, and you don't explain why you don't use it as such.

Comment: Shoudn't it be 15 * 2?

Comment: It is written in the datasheet, you have only 15bit with differential input, and full 16 bit with the Vref trick. Here is a link of the explanation: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa133a/sbaa133a.pdf

Comment: Um, no, I can't find that in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1110.pdf), sorry. What "trick" are you referring to? Page number?

Comment: Updated with link

Comment: That app note does **not** apply to you, because you want to measure a differential signal, as it seems. Converting it to single-endedness just to measure it against a reference voltage is a counter-productive move.

Comment: Again, **define** the input signal's properties (and no, it should **not** be 15 Hz * 2; you've got Nyquist the wrong way around. Also, at a 15- to 16-bit resolution, you really want more than a single stage active filter, or you should stop worrying about a single bit in resolution. Heck, \$4.096\text{ V}/2^{16}=62.5\text{ µV}\$, which is really darn little signal at all, and you must keep a lot of noise out so that you can even theoretically make use of that resolution; I don't think you've thought the overall measurement system through overly well!).

Comment: The ADC reads the (+) signal within +/- 2V the (-) signal. Since my signal ground is probably close to the ADC ground and the ADC can't read negative voltages I need to move the (-) input to 2V to use the full range with full precision

Comment: so your input signal is from -2V to +2V, and is differential? What is its bandwidth? Where does it come from? Please try to describe your signal and don't make me repeat my questions multiple times.

Comment: Signal comes from a transimpedence amp, is a fixed DC, 0-5V, I want to filter both the signal and its ground from accumulated noise. Op amp with single supply

Comment: How flexible are you with the choice of the components?

Comment: @AndreyPro I think quite flexible but I want single supply for the opamp, basically this is the problem

Comment: Can you use SPI or require IIC?

Comment: @AndreyPro yes I can but for what?

Comment: SPI components are  significantly more popular and offer by far wider choice. I will explain in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You over-engineered your module to the point that most people probably have real difficulty to understand, what you are trying to achieve. This how it can (and probably  should be) simplified

1. This ADC is not really suitable for your application. You need something like [AD7172-2](http://www.analog.com/en/products/analog-to-digital-converters/ad7172-2.html#product-samplebuy) that can take handle (pseudo)-differential range of 5 V (with an external voltage reference). So search different manufacturers for suitable ADCa, ideally with integrated input buffers, but pay attention to input voltage limitations.
2. [Delta Sigma ADCs have rather soft requirements](http://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/precisionhub/archive/2015/10/02/the-delta-sigma-advantage-to-anti-aliasing-filters)  for input filters. [Passive filters](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/precisionhub/archive/2015/11/06/three-guidelines-for-designing-anti-aliasing-filters) are totally sufficient. That makes right opamp redundant.
3. Since you measure DC signal, your input filters are not as much about anti-aliasing but more about bandlimiting input noise , and do not need to be that tight. (see the link in 2. in case you still haven't)
4. Directly use differential inputs to measure your signal (assuming you followed recommendation 1), that's how they supposed to be used.Thus you get read of opamps that themselves can be the source of noise.

This is how your circuit should roughly look like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3Po1D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the values of the resistors and capacitors are placeholders and do not represent recommendation for your case. They have to be chosen in accordance with master sampling frequency (of the delta-sigma ADC) and input impedance of the ADC. If there are no input buffers, filter resistors must be low valued (no more than 20 Ohm)

Comment: However, for anyone interested, I found some interesting readings that fits original problem: [1](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/measurement-techniques/instrumentation-amplifier-ground-loop-isolator) [2](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1272503)

Answer (score 0):

Your front-end amplifier is a unity gain difference amplifier. You are free to choose the reference potential for differential to single-ended conversion. Tie R3 to your 2.5 Reference not AGND.

Your CMRR will depend on the matching of your 5k resistors. See http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/deeper-look-into-difference-amplifiers.html